# Partial template load angular ui/ ui router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have about 10 products and each of them has 3 sections (Details, Description, FAQ) and there is a lot of content for each one. So I am using the $stateProvider to change states in a click of `<a>` but I wonder, is there any way that I can load partial files or templates like jQuery uses to access their ID or class?
The thing is that I do not want to have 30 files of templates. I like to have one and just call that one and since the tabs for each product have the same name I do not want to repeat the code for the tabs in each template.html that I create.

Comment: You should be using ng-repeat to iterate the products. Then, based on ng-if/ng-show conditions, you can have different things for each product.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please go throgh [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question so that people can provide you accurate answer and you can get your solution quickly.

Comment: Ok I will try that thanks